# Can 1 CUDA-core to process more than 1 float-point-instruction per clock (Maxwell)?

Tags: cuda

[List of Nvidia GPU - GeForce 900 Series](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_Nvidia_graphics_processing_units#GeForce_900_Series) - there is written that:

> 4 Single precision performance is calculated as **2 times** the number of
>   shaders multiplied by the base core clock speed.

I.e. for example for GeForce GTX 970 we can calculate performance:

1664 Cores * 1050 MHz * **2** = 3 494 GFlops peak (3 494 400 MFlops)

This value we can see in column - Processing Power (peak) GFLOPS - Single Precision.

But why we must **multiple by 2**?

There is written: http://devblogs.nvidia.com/parallelforall/maxwell-most-advanced-cuda-gpu-ever-made/

> SMM uses a quadrant-based design with four 32-core processing blocks
>   each with a dedicated warp scheduler capable of dispatching **two
>   instructions per clock.**

Ok, nVidia Maxwell is superscalar architecture and dispatching two instructions per clock, but can 1 CUDA-core(FP32-ALU) process more than 1 instruction per clock?

We know that 1 CUDA-Core contain two units: FP32-unit and INT-unit. But INT-unit is irrelevant to GFlops (**FLoating-point** Operations Per Second).

I.e. one SMM contain:

- **128 FP32-unit**
- 128 INT-unit
- **32 SFU-unit**
- 32 LD/ST-unit

To get preformance in **GFlops** we should to use only: 128 FP32-units and 32 SFU-units.

I.e. if we use both 128 FP32-units and 32 SFU-units simultaneously, then we can get 160 instructions with float-point operations per clock per 1 SM.

I.e. we must multiple **by 1,2** =(160/132) instad of 2.

1664 Cores * 1050 MHz * **1,2** = 2 096 GFlops peak

Why has write in wiki that we must multiple Cores*MHz by 2?

[image]

[image]

Comment: If the floating-point instruction is an FMA (fused multiply-add), one *instruction* represents two floating-point *operations* (namely, an addition plus a multiplication).

Comment: in addition to @njuffa you should have a look at this [wiki](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/GeForce_500_series#GeForce_500_.285xx.29_series) article which explains the estimation of the peak FLOPs

Comment: @njuffa if you want to provide an answer I would upvote.  The question about multiply-by-2 is explicitly called out and highlighted in this (lengthy) question, so clearly it is an answer of some sort.

Comment: From wiki: "Each SP can fulfil up to two single precision operations FMA per clock. Each SFU can fulfil up to four operations SF per clock." I.e. 1 SM (Maxwell) with 128 Cores can to process (128 FP32 * 2) = 256 FMA operations per clock, or (32 SFU * 4) = 128 SFU operations per clock, is it right?

Comment: The multiplication of `cores*MHz*2` is exactly the calculation you would use to compute peak theoretical SP (single-precision) throughput.  The `*2` multiplier is arising out of the fact that a single FMA instruction counts as 2 floating point operations (a multiply and an add) for purposes of peak theoretical calculation.  There are various questions here on the CUDA tag as well as many references on the web which cover this.  A warp scheduler can issue 2 instructions per clock.  But these 2 instructions *would not be scheduled* on the **same** execution resources *in that clock cycle*.

Comment: One cuda core (SP, or any other execution unit, for that matter) cannot process more than one instruction per clock.  If that instruction is an FMA, it is still one instruction, but *it counts as 2 floating point operations*.

Comment: @Robert Crovella Thank you very much! 1 CUDA-Core FP32 can to process per clock 1 FMA-instruction with 2 floating point operations.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Summary: One FMA counts as 2 [FLOP](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/FLOPS)s in the standard accounting of FP throughput, even on machines that do it in a single instruction for a single execution unit (which is how it avoids intermediate rounding, the [*fused* part of FMA](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multiply%E2%80%93accumulate_operation)).

---

A CUDA "core" (also called SP - streaming processor) is most commonly referring to the single-precision floating point units in an SM (streaming multiprocessor).  A CUDA core can initiate one single precision floating point instruction per clock cycle.  (The unit is pipelined, so it can initiate one instruction per clock, and it can retire one instruction per clock, but it cannot fully process a given instruction in a given clock cycle.)

If that instruction is for example, a single-precision add or single precision multiply, then that core can contribute one floating point **operation** per clock, since an add or multiply counts as one floating point operation.  If, on the other hand, the instruction is an FMA instruction (floating point multiply-add) then the core will perform both a floating point multiply *AND* a floating point add operation in the same time period.  This means that effectively two **operations** are performed by a single **instruction**.  This usage of FMA gives rise to the 2 multiplier when computing peak theoretical throughput.

So a core can only process (i.e. initiate, retire) a single instruction per clock, but if that instruction is an FMA, it counts as two floating point operations.

Comment: Thank you very much! I.e. can we say, that SP (CUDA-Core) contain a long pipeline with number of stages for two operations: 1st mul and 2nd add?

Comment: Yes, an SP core has a pipeline.  And it can handle any of the designated SP-FP instructions.

Comment: then there could be 1 add + 1 mul + 1 integer add + 1 intteger mul "in-flight"(or in "execute" pipeline stages) per core?

Comment: @Alex: No, it's not really a separate mul and add.  The "fused" part of FMA means there's no rounding of the intermediate `mul` result.  An FMA execution unit physically as well as logically does both at once, potentially doing some of the mantissa addition work as part of adding up the partial products from the multiply.  (Although I'm not 100% sure about that; FP FMA is more complicated than integer MAC because different exponents mean the addend can line up with a totally separate part of the final mantissa than the product.  Integer MAC can just take the +c as one more thing to add up.)